# Mockito How to test a findById by UUID

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have problems with a Test Class.

In my class ParkingSpotService there is a Method findByid by UUID and I want write a test for this:

```
@Transactional
public Optional<ParkingSpotModel> findById(UUID id) {
    return parkingSpotRepository.findById(id);
}
```

What I did? I created a TestClass ParkingSpotServiceTest:

```
@SpringBootTest                                                                    
public class ParkingSpotServiceTest {

private static final UUID ID = UUID.fromString("35361d85-107c-4f1f-a047-263093161c1b");
private static final String PARKINGSPOTNUMBER = "1010";
private static final String LICENSEPLATECAR = "EAM3J81";
private static final String MODELCAR = "FIT";
private static final String BRANDCAR = "HONDA";
private static final String COLORCAR = "GREEN";
private static final LocalDateTime REGISTRATIONDATE = LocalDateTime.now();          
private static final String RESPONSIBLENAME = "Edison Azevedo";     
private static final String APARTMENT = "51";
private static final String BLOCK = "A";            

@InjectMocks
private ParkingSpotService service;

@Mock
private ParkingSpotRepository repository;

private ParkingSpotModel parkingSpot;   
private Optional<ParkingSpotModel> optionalParkingSpot;
Pageable pageable;

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    startParkingSpot();
}

private void startParkingSpot() {
    parkingSpot = new ParkingSpotModel(ID, 
                                       PARKINGSPOTNUMBER, 
                                       LICENSEPLATECAR, 
                                       BRANDCAR, 
                                       MODELCAR, 
                                       COLORCAR, 
                                       REGISTRATIONDATE, 
                                       RESPONSIBLENAME, 
                                       APARTMENT, 
                                       BLOCK);      
    
    optionalParkingSpot = Optional.of(new ParkingSpotModel(ID, 
                                                           PARKINGSPOTNUMBER, 
                                                           LICENSEPLATECAR, 
                                                           BRANDCAR, 
                                                           MODELCAR, 
                                                           COLORCAR, 
                                                           REGISTRATIONDATE, 
                                                           RESPONSIBLENAME, 
                                                           APARTMENT, 
                                                           BLOCK));                 
}
```

}

And after I created a test

```
@Test
void whenFindParkingSpotByIDThenReturnAnParkingSpotInstance() {     
    Mockito.when(repository.findById(Mockito.any(UUID.class))).thenReturn(optionalParkingSpot); 
    Optional<ParkingSpotModel> response = service.findById(ID); 
    **//above my response is value = null  ->  Optional.empty.    Why????????** 
    Assertions.assertNotNull(response);     
    
    Assertions.assertEquals(java.util.Optional.class, response.getClass());             
    
    Assertions.assertEquals(ID, response.get().getId());
    //here my test broke because my response "java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present"
```

Observations:

1. When I inspect optionalParkingSpot, all datas are there. `Mockito.when(repository.findById(Mockito.any(UUID.class))).thenReturn(optionalParkingSpot);`
2. When I inspect the ID, apears my UUID correctly (35361d85-107c-4f1f-a047-263093161c1b) `Optional<ParkingSpotModel> response = service.findById(ID);`

What is wrong with my "response"?   Why the data is value = null  ->  Optional.empty.    ???

Comment: The code looks good to my eyes, apart that you don't need `@SpringBootTest`. Two primary suspects are: 1. incorrect injection of mock to system under test (with your debugger check that SUT uses the mock) 2. stubbing the wrong overload.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the order of calls in your `@BeforeEach` annotated method is correct? You first initialize the mocks with `MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this)` and after that you initialize the values that should be injected? I would suggest you try it the other way round.

```java
@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    startParkingSpot();
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
}
```

Also don't forget to release the mocks as described in https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html

Alternatively you could remove the Annotations and inject the mocks created with `Mockito.mock(...)` manually.

Comment: I tried changing the position but unfortunately occurred the same problem.